# Telerik MVC Treeview Action

Tags: c#, javascript, treeview, telerik, telerik-mvc

```
<%:
    Html.Telerik().TreeView()
    .Name("ZebTree")
    .ExpandAll(false)
    .ClientEvents(events => events.OnSelect("TreeView_onSelect"))
    .BindTo(Model , map =>
            {
                map.For<TreeViewBind.Models.Category>(bind => bind.ItemDataBound((item, category) => { item.Text = category.CategoryName; }).Children(category => category.Products));
                map.For<TreeViewBind.Models.Product>(bind => bind.ItemDataBound((item, product) => { item.Text = product.ProductName;}));
            }        
    )
%>
```

Above is the code for generating tree in telerik mvc. I want to perform action by selecting the node. When somebody click on specific node i want it to navigate to about page and passing the text of that node as argument to about page.

Comment: You already have a clientevent hooked up in the code you've provided. What's your exact problem?

Comment: Simon its just the event on which that will be called. I want the implementation of OnSelect event(TreeView_OnSelect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo guys,

Actually there is a method called Action which you can use to specify the action which you want your item to point to. You probably don't see it because the intellisence is quite confused. You can be a bit more specific like this:

```
.BindTo(Model,(NavigationBindingFactory<TreeViewItem> mappings) =>
    {
        mappings.For<Category>(binding => binding
                .ItemDataBound((item, category) =>
                {
                    item.Action("Test", "Home", new{text=category.CategoryName});//here you can assign the action method , the last parameter is the route values
                    item.Text = category.CategoryName;
                })
     }
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

OnSelect prototype:

```
function TreeView_onSelect(e) {

}
```

The e only has 1 element, "item", which is the LI element that's been selected. So, an example would be:

```
function TreeView_onSelect(e) {
    alert($(e.item).text());
}
```

See here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-treeview-client-api-and-events.html#ClientEvents